# Upload files to create nodes

Tags: nodes

I am trying to create an online catalog of products, that could be filtered, sorted, etc, and I followed these steps:

- I have created a content type (product)
- I have created a view where I can view and filter/sort these products

Now, the major problem is to manually enter hundreds of products!
I have product descriptions in Excel, and image files with links, but I don't know how to upload everything in bulk.

How could I do this?

Comment: if you have an excel sheet, then you can create its csv. Now create a php script that will iterate through every entries and create node programmatically

Comment: Welcome to DA! I've written down an answer that should be appropriate for both a "site builder" and a "developer" role. I'm not sure how well Feeds will handle images, but I wish you the best of luck and hope my answer is of use to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maximum flexibility:**

I would use the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. It has CSV support, and there's even direct [spreadsheet support](https://drupal.org/node/1751438) in the works. [Migrate documentation](http://drupal.org/node/415260).

It will require some coding, yes, and Migrate module is not the easiest module to get a grip on, so if you're new to coding, you may need some help with that, but I think it's by far the best solution.

**Easier implementation:**

The [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module claims that it can

> Import or aggregate CSV files

I haven't used that particular piece of functionality myself, but from previous use of Feeds, I'm under the impression that this could be configured from the UI, and thus wouldn't require any code. [Feeds documentation](http://drupal.org/node/622696).

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me and of course for your help! I'll definitely check out Migrate module to import text fields. As for images - I will still be waiting suggestions from DA community. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome. :) Migrate handles files (and thus images) just fine. Not sure about feeds though.

Comment: I used feeds combined with feeds tamper module to upload text and multi-value fields and it worked great! thanks again!